# $(window).load Strange Behavior on Refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a loading mask that I would like to fadeOut() once the entire page has loaded.  It works perfectly on the first time the user enters the page, but if they refresh, the loading mask disappears before the page has loaded.  I have read quite a few articles out there and it seems that the common problem is that $(window)load usually doesn't fire events because of cache, but in my case it is fired too quickly upon refresh...What could be the issue?

```
 1. <html>
   2.       <head><script type="text/javascript">
   3.             Ext.onReady(function() {....});
   4.             $(window).load(function(){$('#loading-mask').fadeOut(5000); $('#loading').fadeOut(5000);});
   5.       </script></head>
   6.       <body>
   7.             <div id="loading-mask"></div>
   8.             <div id="loading">
   9.                   <span id="loading-message">Loading Tibet...</span>
  10.              </div>
  11.       </body>
  12.  </html>
```

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks,

elshae

Comment: Why do you have the window.load inside an Ext.onReady?

Comment: second time you have all the elements availabe in browsers caches itself , so that window onload will be as quick as possible..

Comment: @eshae , i don't think you should do this kind of effects in window onload

Comment: @Josiah, it is not inside the Ext.onReady code, but admittedly I tried that too and did not have the right results either.  @gov, I want the layer mask to fade as soon as everything on the page has loaded.  From what I have read $(window).load handles this.  It does make sense to me that the browser would cache itself, but the thing is that I can see image and the like loading on my page after the mask fades...if the browser is caching, wouldn't the page be loaded before the $(window).load anyway???

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found out that it's best if JavaScript code is placed in the body..

So now I have all my code in the body including the Ext.onReady, so here goes...

```
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body onload="">

            <div id="loading-mask"></div>
            <div id="loading">
              <span id="loading-message">Loading Tibet...</span>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">

            //Default blank image needed for some ExtJS widgets/if no image is found...
            Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL = "./ext-3.2.1/resources/images/default/s.gif";

            Ext.onReady(function() {
                .............
             });

//Outside Ext.onReady
 window.onload = function(){$('#loading-mask').fadeOut(5000); $('#loading').fadeOut(5000);}

</body></html>

//The css is:

#loading-mask {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     /*background: #D8D8D8;*/
    /* background: #6E6E6E;*/
    background: #000000;
     opacity: .8;
     z-index: 1;
}
#loading {
     position: absolute;
     top: 40%;
     left: 45%;
     z-index: 2;
}
#loading span {
     /*background: url('ajax-loader.gif') no-repeat left center;*/
     background: url('globe.gif') no-repeat left center;
     color: #BDBDBD;
     width: 60%;
     height: 30%;
     padding: 60px 70px;
     display: block;
}
```